# Contao Database update always shows ALTER TABLE with unchanged column

Tags: contao

I am using contao 4 but I had this problem already in version 3.
I have created a table with some columns. One of this column is marked as `int(10) default NULL`. Nothing special about that.
However: When I run my database upate, this column is always shown as changed.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `tl_products` CHANGE `tags` `tags` int(10) default NULL;
> ```

It doenst matter how often I press upate. This statement never disappears.
I already saw that at different other cases (e.g. when one writes `default 0` instead of `default '0'`). Does anyone know how to fix this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct definition is

```
int(10) NULL
```

which should work in Contao. Your previous definition, `int(10) default NULL` is shorthand for `int(10) NOT NULL default NULL`, which makes no sense of course (thus it cannot be detected by Contao).

Comment: As discussed here: https://github.com/contao/core/issues/8393 `int(10) NULL` should work, since `int(10) default NULL` is the SQL shortform for `int(10) NOT NULL default NULL` (which is nonsense of course).

Comment: I suggest to correct your answer to make things right :)

Comment: Yeah, I will do once I have confirmed all the details myself :).